# How do I visualize with precision what happens after the last command of the main pathway of a program?

Tags: python, control-flow, control-flow-graph

I have been drawing educational comics that explain basic programming concepts. At the moment, I'm doing one about control flow, and one area boggles my mind: What the computer does, after finishing all the commands of the program's final main pathway in the control flow.

I assumed it would "exit" out of the program as a way to end it, but other sources say *very* passively, "The program exits out of the computer." This part sounds weird to me, as when I visualized control flow, the computer is doing commands one by one, until it hits an "ending" of the program of some kind.

This is the draft of my work to explain what I'm dealing with:

https://prairieworldcomicsblog.files.wordpress.com/2018/03/controlflowpencil.pdf

At the end of this comic, what is the best metaphor to visualize this "ending" here?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, when you ask a question you have to be specific about what you are asking and avoid opinion based questions. For more information you can see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I tried my best to do just that. If there was any better way for me to ask it, please let me know.

Comment: My theory is that "what happens after the last command" is up to you, as long as it's some form of "exiting."  A more specific question might be "what happens after syscall exit," since almost every program that voluntarily halts does so by calling this

Answer (score 1):

Well, at some level, you can just think of the OS as a higher level program that hands off control to the user's program for a while (the reality is more complicated with `fork` and many processes running in parallel, but you can probably ignore that). When the program ends, control goes back to the OS, just like control goes back to the main flow after a function ends in a program.

So maybe you should just have a "warp portal" at the end of the program, and describe how it warps you back to the control flow of an OS program (such as a command prompt).

I have one suggestion about some of your imagery, that's unrelated to your current question. It might be easier to depict some control structures like `else` branches if you use forks and merges in the control-flow "road", rather than always using warp portals that take you back to the main path. The portals absolutely are useful, but I'd limit them to things like calling and returning from functions.

An `if` (and `elif`/`else`) is just a fork in the road. The two (or more) branches can recombine after a while, so you might have something like this, if you'll forgive my terrible ASCII art:

```
       --> if block -->
      /                \
--> if -> else block -> regular control flow resumes ->
```

A `while` loop is very similar, it just has the flow of its block running the other direction, so you merge *before* the branch split off:

```
  <- while block <-
 /                 \
|                   ^
v                   |
 \                 /
---> while condition -> regular control flow resumes ->
```

Comment: So in other words, "the computer exits that program" - not "the program exits the computer", right?

Comment: Right. Control flow can occur between programs, not only within a single one.

Comment: I understand your suggestions. The main reason I used portals was for readability. Complex control flow charts get all tangled up and confusing to me when the trip going back gets mixed with the trip going in across multiple branches. I admit that warp panels are kind of experimental, though.

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter's lifecycle is visualized at https://wiki.python.org/moin/CPythonInterpreterInitialization . The finalization part is basically:

- `sts` = <result from running user code, in whatever mode was requested>
- [`Py_Finalize()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html?highlight=py_finalize#c.Py_Finalize)
- exit with status `sts`

What `Py_Finalize` does is not explained there. Some explanation is in [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html?highlight=py_finalize#c.Py_Finalize):

> Undo all initializations made by `Py_Initialize()` and subsequent use of
>   Python/C API functions, and destroy all sub-interpreters that were created and not yet destroyed <...>
>
> Bugs and caveats: The destruction of modules and objects in modules is
>   done in random order; this may cause destructors (`__del__()` methods)
>   to fail when they depend on other objects (even functions) or modules.
>   <...>

So, roughly speaking, it garbage-collects all objects including modules. It also calls `atexit` handlers before that. The function's source can be found [in `pythonrun.c` for Py2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/pythonrun.c#L411) and in [`pythonlifecycle.c` for Py3](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pylifecycle.c#L1019)<sup>1</sup> where you can get a more precize picture.

I dunno how to to express that in a children's comic (that said, you didn't cover initialization sequence, either) but basically, this is what happens.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>where it consists solely of a call to `Py_FinalizeEx`, so I linked to that routine directly.</sub>

Comment: So if I'm reading correctly, the ending seems to be more like an "off switch" instead of just the computer exiting the program. Is that it?

Comment: @WilliamWise Basically, yes, except the fact it also does any necessary cleanup steps (like flushing I/O buffers). It also generates an exit code for the OS.

Comment: So it is an off switch that also makes the computer exit out of the program and clean up after itself...

Comment: @WilliamWise Yes, exactly. BlckknghtYou described it very well. I didn't do the same because you were asking about Python specifically, so I assumed you're familiar with general process lifecycle stuff.

Answer (score 0):

A computer program is like a small town (or main city) that is built on the roads of your trips, and the computer might be the country (or the earth maybe).

When you start a new program, it is like you are visiting that city with your car (or on foot). You either pass through the main street and exit the town without doing anything (maybe a saying "Hello Folks"), or decide to go to a shop maybe (where you answered an IF question "you wanna shop?"). Then you love the town and wanted to stay a few days here (another answered IF). now you are in a loop of "wake up, eat breakfast, go outside, have fun, eat lunch, go for more fun, eat dinner, sleep" for a few days. every activity here has its own decision trees and loops too. in the end, you drive your car to the exit again and leave the town.

that's it! you leave the town and continue your journey to another town. it is there to visit another day, as a program written on a disk. it is just not a part of your current active trip. that's all.

oh, by the way, you are the CPU of this analogy. you are the one to execute all these plans. if you have a friend or family with you, this means you can do multitasking too. you could be the programmer too if you plan this whole journey.

what happens when a program ends is just a deletion from the active memory until next run, not from the computer. just like that small town. the computer continues to execute other active programs alongside its operating system on which we run multiple programs simultaneously (multitasking). what is the analogy to shut down the computer? you can imagine I guess.

ps: this is not just a python related topic, you know that, right?

Comment: So my comic's analogy is fairly accurate... Is it? "The computer exits that said program 'town'."

Comment: "a exits b" is a bit confusing in this context. the computer is what programs run ON; CPU (and OS) runs a program; the program is a TO-DO list during execution. when you start a program, you tell the OS to get the instructions from disk to memory. then OS and CPU runs the program with inputs/outputs from/to user. then you click exit, and OS stops the program and deletes its content from memory. but it stays on the disk with changes you made. so an "exit" is not a real thing here. but if you want something to exit, then you should care about what is entering too.....

Comment: .... with town analogy, you travel around, enter a town, spend some time, exit the town, exit to open roads or to next town. so neither computer nor program exits. you "exit". and you are the analogy to CPU/OS.